# Open random file in a folder (and include exceptions) - in batch

Tags: batch-file, random

i'd like to create a batch file for opening a random file within a folder and all of it's subfolders.

I'd also like to add "exception folders" - folders, which are excluded from the random opening.

Currently, i'm using this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Create numbered list of files in a temporary file
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0_fileList_%time::=.%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d %1 | findstr /n "^" >"%tempFile%"

:: Count the files
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N

call :openRandomFile

:: Delete the temp file
del "%tempFile%"

exit /b

:openRandomFile
set /a "randomNum=(%random% %% cnt) + 1"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr "^%randomNum%:" "%tempFile%"'
) do start "" "%%B"
exit /b
```

It works perfectly for the random opening, **but i'm not sure how i could exclude some of the subfolders within the specific directory.**

**Thank you in advance for your help! :)**

Comment: Use robocopy with its /L and /XD switches for your numbered list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to provide a solution which uses the idea I gave in my comment;

```cmd
@Echo Off

(Set SrcDir=C:\Users\teapuppets\Documents)
(Set ToExcl=mortgage invoices)

Set "i=0"
For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (
    'Robocopy "%SrcDir%" NULL /L /S /FP /NDL /NS /NC /NJH /NJS /XD %ToExcl%'
    ) Do (Set/A i+=1
    Call Set File[%%i%%]=%%A)

Set/A "RndNum=(%random% %% i) + 1"
Call Start "" "%%File[%RndNum%]%%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%N in ('type "%tempFile%" ^| findstr /v /g:exclude_me_file.txt ^|find /c /v ""') do set cnt=%%N
```

Where `exclude_me_file.txt` contains the directories-to-exclude, one to a line

Comment: Let me recommend some changes: add `/L` to `findstr` to force literal search strings; add `/I` to search case-insensitively (like Windows also treats file paths); each directory in the exclusions file should be preceded by a backslash and appended by another one to not match partial directory names unintentionally...